# Which is the most extensible image gallery plugin for JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've tried Jcarousel as my image gallery plugin, but I don't know if there's another one more extensible than this, do you know one?
 I'd rather prefer that it could connect to an AJAX source of images to display, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/).

Comment: very nice gallery James, seems pretty powerful

Comment: You might be right, but since the link is about a specific product, any extra information without the actual (working) link is completely irrelevant and useless.